If $a(x)\sim a_1 (x)$ and $b(x)\sim b_1 (x)$ then $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{a_1(x)}{b_1(x)}$?
I'm trying to prove the following:

If $a(x)\sim a_1 (x)$ and $b(x)\sim b_1 (x)$ as $x\to a$, then:
$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{a_1(x)}{b_1(x)}$$

Definition: $a(x) \sim b(x)$ means that $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=1$.

There is a theorem given before that:
If $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=C\neq 0$ then there is $\delta>0$ and constants $c_1, c_2$ such that:
$$|x-a|<\delta \implies c_1 b(x) \leq a(x) \leq c_2 b(x)$$
Which could be useful somehow but I can't come up with anything. Can you give me a hint?

$a/b\sim a_1/b_1.$

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a}{a_1}\cdot\frac{b_1}{b}\cdot\frac{a_1}{b_1}.$$

Hint:
$$\frac{a_1(x)}{b_1(x)}=\frac{a_1(x)}{a(x)}\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}\frac{b(x)}{b_1(x)}$$
Also, you have to assume something before you put limits. What is that?

That the limits exist and the property about the product of limits?

@RedBanana: Correct!
